# Automatic duplicate answers flags for not duplicate answers?

Tags: support

I've seen a few (2-3) flags marked "Duplicate answers (auto)".

However, at least by the time I get to look at the question, there hasn't been a duplicate answer, so I've flagged the flag as incorrect.

Should I just keep doing that if it keeps happening, or is something else going on that I don't understand?

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that flags for duplicated answers are raised when the answer is first posted, probably after the grace period. When the answer is edited, the flag is not automatically dismissed in the same way it happens with other flags.

For example, there is a flag for duplicated answer on [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/100207/199), which is said to be a duplicate of [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/100206/199), which now appears different, but [it was really a duplicate when first posted](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/100206/1).

The reason why those flags are not automatically dismissed is evident with those answers: While the answer was edited, its meaning doesn't change; only a human being can tell if the duplicated answer means a duplicated question, or if there are other actions that need to be taken.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know which questions/answers you are talking about, and I handled the flag.

The auto-duplicate-flag for answers will be raised when it thinks there is a *near* duplicate, and not just an *exact* duplicate.

Treat the **Community ♦** the same as others with regards to flags.  The choice does get logged, and may influence algorithms in the future.

See also:

- [Valid vs Invalid dismissals of Community flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75728/valid-vs-invalid-dismissals-of-community-flags)
- [Where, precisely, does feedback on Community ♦ generated flags go to die?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105813/where-precisely-does-feedback-on-community-generated-flags-go-to-die)

Comment: Actually, the flag is raised on the first post of the answer. If successive edits change it, the flag is not automatically dismissed.